# Paring Large Numbers Question

Tags: python

I am writing some simple code to raise a base value to a power
then perform some operations on the output.  I have included the code I am
using now, below ( see end of this message ), also see immediately below
what this looks like when I run my script from the console ;

```
C:\PYTHON34>python tst.py
INPUT Value: 431.1
INPUT Power Value; 1.9907
RESULT 1739.554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000
```

What I need to be able to do is:

1. Store whole number value to left of the decimal point without decimals to a variable = x
2. Grab entire decimal value to the right of the decimal point and store in a variable = y

Parse (y) according to some simple rules. Here it is where it gets trick for me.

What I want to do is examine (y) to see if there are any leading leading and trailing zeros

In the example `1739.554505.....`, if this value was instead, something like any of the following

```
1739.0554505
1739.00554505
1739.000554505
```

Then, I want to extract the whole number less any continuous leading zeroes.

Next, I want to cut the number so that when there are four continuous trailing zeros, all zeros starting from the first one that started off the first four continuous zeros and all following zeroes are truncated.

So in our example

```
1739.554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000
```

(y) becomes `55450564142665825784206390380859375`

Next, I want to take the mod of above value by %1999. This returns `1407`.

Next, I want to join this value AS the decimal value to the right as

```
1739.1407
```

Ok, so now why am I stuck at this point?

I'm still fairly new to learning Python so I don't actually know what the best ways are to do this.

I'm thinking I could maybe just do a trim on the value to the right of the decimal, take that, convert the whole thing to a string, then chop up each digit and store each individually to an array then code a rule set for stepping through strings in array cells, but this also seems like it could take more CPU  time than I'd like.  I'm hoping to perform this sort of operation fast, as fast as possible.

Also, I do not even know how to best approach this even if I had to store this as a string into an array, and if I understand correctly string processing tends to takes more CPU time than number calculations.

Any insight, direction, code suggestions greatly appreciated!

This is the code I am currently using

```
import time
e0=time.time()
c0=time.clock()

import sys
import math
from sympy import mpmath
from mpmath import *
mpmath.mp.dps = 10000


inputx = float(input('Enter inputx Value: '))
powerx =float(input('Enter Power Value; '))

inputx_squared = float((mpmath.power(inputx, powerx)))%1999

print('\r')
print('RESULT ', '%.60f' % inputx_squared)

elapsed_time=time.time() -e0
cpu_time=time.clock() -c0

print('\r')
print("CPU TIME ;", cpu_time)
```

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. I think that your question is better suited for Stack Overflow, since it is about programming and not about Computational Science.